# Create a variable based on other factors using R

Tags: r, database, dataframe, variables, var

I have a data frame and I want to create a variable based on other factors, my data contains :

| qi | pi | exep |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 300 | 16 |
| 2 | 245 | 14 |
| 3 | 300 | 5 |

I want to create the based salary

based_salary = pi+α(qi*exep)

α is between (0 and 1)

And the only accurate information about based salary is (from real data) :

Mean(based_salary) == 268

So how can I determine (α) to calculate based_salary...

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(x = qi * exep) %>%
  summarise(p = mean(pi),
            x = mean(x))
a = (268 - df1$p)/df1$x # = alpha : -0.4505495
df %>%
  mutate(bs = pi + a * (qi * exep)) %>%
  summarise(mean_bs = mean(bs))

  mean_bs
1     268
```